# Fetching user based access token using grant type as password

Tags: asp.net, azure, access-token, azure-authentication

I am trying to retrieve access token by using user credential.

I am using AcquireTokenAsync method for retrieving the token where I am using constructor with resource, client id and user credential as parameter.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetToken()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        try
        {
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant";
            string resource ="2424-234-234234-234-23-32423";
            string username = "yxyzzz";
            string password = "password";
           string clientId="2424-234-234234-234-23-32423";
            var useridpassword = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            context.TokenCache.Clear();
            authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, useridpassword);
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I am expecting access token to be returned but I am getting an exception while acquiring token. Below is the error message I am getting.

```
AdalException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\nTrace ID: 674f29fe-73c6-49a3-9c3f-24df4ea16000\r\nCorrelation ID: b14cb535-9df5-48fa-b911-7e8b927fceb7\r\nTimestamp: 2019-11-08 06:21:57Z","error_codes":[7000218],"timestamp":"2019-11-08 06:21:57Z","trace_id":"674f29fe-73c6-49a3-9c3f-24df4ea16000","correlation_id":"b14cb535-9df5-48fa-b911-7e8b927fceb7","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000218"}: Unknown error
```

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Comment: Yeah.. Able to get token by calling Oauth2/token endpoint.

Comment: I have shared the code which worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it, you can make it as answer. Then this issue can be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i am using to fetch token. This is what i wanted to retrieve the access token.

```
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant";
        string resource ="2424-234-234234-234-23-32423";
        string username = "yxyzzz";
        string password = "password";
       string clientId="2424-234-234234-234-23-32423";
            string tokenEndpointUri = authority + "/oauth2/token";
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", authmodel.ClientId),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", authmodel.ClientSecret),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", resource)
    }
            );
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage res = null;
                    client.PostAsync(tokenEndpointUri, content).
                    ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            res = t.Result;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    })
                    .Wait();

                string json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
```

I am getting access token in json variable with other details. If you want to fetch the token value, then you can deserialize it to .net Object and get the value.

Answer (score 1):

To use resource owner password credential, you need to treat application as a public client.

Go to azure portal->App registrations->find your application->check the advanced settings

[image]